# iOS - How to control the width of leftBarButton of navigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, size, uinavigationbar

There is a requirement to enforce min and max width of the leftbarbutton on navigation bar. The text on leftbarbutton is supposed to display elipsis for additional characters that won't fit in the max width.

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftbarButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Sample Title" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil] autorelease]; [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: leftbarButton];
```